# Mount a shared Azure disk in Azure Kubernetes to multiple windows PODs

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, windows-container, azure-disk

I want to attach a shared disk to multiple windows containers on AKS.
From [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67078009/5278076) learned that it can be done for Linux containers.

I am trying to do the same with windows container but it's failing to mount a shared disk, with below error

> MapVolume.MapPodDevice failed for volume "pvc-6e07bdca-2126-4a5b-806a-026016c3798d" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not mount "2" at "\var\lib\kubelet\plugins\kubernetes.io\csi\volumeDevices\publish\pvc-6e07bdca-2126-4a5b-806a-026016c3798d\4e44da87-ea33-4d85-a7db-076db0883bcf": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = not an absolute Windows path: 2
> [Error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJjlo.png)

Used below to dynamically provision Shared Azure Disk

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: managed-csi-custom
provisioner: disk.csi.azure.com
parameters:
  skuname: Premium_LRS  
  maxShares: "2"
  cachingMode: None
reclaimPolicy: Delete
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-azuredisk-dynamic
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi  
  volumeMode: Block
  storageClassName: managed-csi-custom
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-shared-disk
  name: deployment-azuredisk
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-shared-disk
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-shared-disk
      name: deployment-azuredisk
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        role: windowsgeneral
      containers:
        - name: deployment-azuredisk
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
          volumeDevices:
            - name: azuredisk
              devicePath: "D:\test"
      volumes:
        - name: azuredisk
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-azuredisk-dynamic
```

Is it possible to mount shared disk for windows container on AKS? Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please use the  device path as like did in thread you shared **devicePath: /dev/sdx** or another location in C drive.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT: Yes tried, faced the same issue.

Comment: Mouting while provisioning the windows pods is not possible, So in onder to overcome this you have to deploye the pods first and then followed this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-csi#windows-containers) for the share disk using the CSI driver

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the exact error trying to mount a managed disk to a windows cluster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Azure shared disks is an Azure managed disks feature that enables attaching an Azure disk to agent nodes simultaneously. But it doesn't apply for window node pool only***

To overcome this issue or mounting `Azure Disk CSI driver` to window node you need to provisoned or create the window node pool first.
Please refer this [***MS tutorial***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli) to add a Windows node pool.

After you have a Windows node pool, you can now use the same built-in storage classes ***managed-csi*** to mount the DISK.

For more information and Validating Volume Mapping you can refer this ***[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-csi#windows-containers)***